# Error in admin page Ui grid

Tags: magento2, admin, ui-grid

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: arguments in /var/www/dev-romanl/web/vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Data.php on line 162
What could it be ? how to fix ?

> layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="feedback_feedback_grid" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> feedback_feedback_grid

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">feedback_feedback_grid_listing.feedback_feedback_grid_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">feedback_feedback_grid_listing.feedback_feedback_grid_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">feedback_grid_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Entity</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="feedback_feedback_grid_listing_data_source">

    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">

    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="feedback_grid_columns">

    </columns>
</listing>
```

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Ronis\Feedback\Api\FeedbackRepositoryInterface" type="Ronis\Feedback\Model\FeedbackRepository" />
    <preference for="Ronis\Feedback\Api\Feedback\FeedbackInterface" type="Ronis\Feedback\Model\Feedback" />
    <virtualType name="FeedbackFeedbackGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\FeedbackProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="FeedbackFeedbackGridFeedbackProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Ronis\Feedback\Model\Resource\Feedback\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">FeedbackFeedbackGridFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Ronis\Feedback\Model\ResourceModel\Feedback\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">ronis_feedback_feedback</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Ronis\Feedback\Model\ResourceModel\Feedback</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="feedback_feedback_grid_feedback_source" xsi:type="string">Ronis\Feedback\Model\ResourceModel\Feedback\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Ronis\Feedback\Controller\Adminhtml\Feedback\MassDelete">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="successMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.</argument>
            <argument name="errorMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">An error occurred while deleting record(s).</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Ronis\Feedback\Controller\Adminhtml\Feedback\MassDisable">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="successMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">A total of %1 data have been disabled.</argument>
            <argument name="errorMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">An error occurred while disabling selected data.</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Ronis\Feedback\Controller\Adminhtml\Feedback\MassEnable">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="successMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">A total of %1 data have been enabled.</argument>
            <argument name="errorMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">An error occurred while enabling data.</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```